# Running scripts while using require('some_module.js') - good practice?

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs

I am talking about server side js (with node.js and require.js)
I have three files

```
//1) app.js - main entry point:
//=======================================================
var myservice = require('./myservice');

rt.register('someKey', require('./XYZhandler').handler);

//2) myservice.js:
//=======================================================
var handlers = {};

exports.register = function(key, handler) {
    handlers[key] = handler;
};

//3) and finally XYZhandler.js:
//=======================================================
exports.handler = function() {
    //...do something
};
```

So, in the above setup I have all script that actually executes explicit in app.js

The alternative I had was:

```
//1) app.js - main entry point:
//=======================================================
var myservice = require('./myservice'),
    rt = require('./XYZhandler');

//2) myservice.js: unchanged from above

//3)and finally XYZhandler.js:
//=======================================================
require('./myservice').register(function() {
    //...do that same thing
};
```

In this latter setup, I have script in XYZhandler.js that actually gets executed the first time requirejs encounters it (note that XYZhandler.js doesn't export anything). I (as a Java developer) liken this to **static initializers**. But which of the above is considered a better practice? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The first approach is better because it is properly decoupled.

In the second approach `XYZhandler.js` depends on `myservice.js`.  If `yourhandler.js` or `hishandler.js` want to `register` `XYZhandler.js`, they too will have to be hard-coded in. Pretty soon, all your modules will depend on one another and you won't have any ability to reuse them individually, which is the entire point of abstracting those functions to modules in the first place.

It's a cosmetic difference, but I'd probably write your first example this way:

```
//1) app.js - main entry point:
//=======================================================
var myservice = require('./myservice');
var myhandler = require('./XYZhandler').handler;

rt.register('someKey', myhandler);
```

Loading modules in one step, then initializing them helps me clarify their relationship.

Hope that helps!